# add rtf to MS Access field during CREATE TABLE in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, rtf, create-table, alter-table

From my VB.net application I manage to create a database.
I can also create tables, with all kinds of datatypes in them.  (with much thanks to stackoverflow's contributors!)
so far so good...
but how do I set the datatype MEMO to accept rich text?

basically how do I code to get : (MS Access snippet)

[image]

I'm sure it is a simple addition to the regular CREATE TABLE business - but I don't know what!

any hints would be most appreciated!

Comment: Do you realize that what Access calls _Rich Text_ is really a subset of HTML?  That said, I believe that you will need to change direction and use the "Microsoft Office XX.Y Access database engine Object Library" (a COM library reference) to manipulate these Access specific field properties.  That means DAO style with a DataBase object, a TableDef object, then a Field object.  With the Field object you can manipulate its properties collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do anything to make the Memo data type accept RTF data. RTF is text and a Memo column stores text. Job done. Many of those fields you're setting on the column are about how Access DISPLAYS the data within Access itself, not how it stores it. If you're using the MDB or ACCDB file simply as storage and the data only gets displayed in your application then that Text Format is irrelevant.